# Is there a standard data model for HTTP Requests/Responses?

Tags: database, http, data-modeling, datamodel

I have a rest service (implemented using JAX-RS) and I need to store the details of each request/response in a relation database.  I'm using Servlet filters to get the request/response information.  I'm wondering, is there some kind of standard database schema model HTTP requests/responses?

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I'm aware of.

You could model your own tables based on the HTTP Request / Response fields. 
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html

Of course you can obtain these values using the HttpRequest and HttpResponse .NET classes.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpResponse(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest(v=vs.110).aspx